# python pandas - good option for processing website analytics?

Tags: python, pandas, analytics

I currently store various site events (impressions, click events, page section views, etc) in simpledb for raw data logging and I'm exploring the best way to process this data.

Since pandas looks to fit the bill with so many different methods of querying (haven't done in depth research yet), I'm thinking about exporting all records (or incremental records) from simpledb once a day into CSV files and then loop through all the csv's and import into pandas.

There would be around 15 columns in the csv, and probably 10's of millions of records.

Would this be a good option for processing the analytics? Or could someone suggest a better alternative?

Comment: that would work; if you need multi-day processing, consider appending to an ``HDFStore`` (and then you can actually have nice query ability as well), see: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#hdf5-pytables